# How to use UssdResponseCallback and sendUssdRequest?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, ussd

I want to build an app that users can send money using USSD. When the user tries to send I don't want the activity to go the Phone app, I want the USSD dialog to open while the user is still using my app and get the response.
So I tried to use the sendUssdRequest and UssdResponseCallback which is new to me and I couldn't find how to use them. So how can I use them for the purpose of this app?

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66961745/i-there-a-way-to-run-an-interactive-ussd-session-and-hide-the-session-behind-a-l/68148632#68148632) which has an probable answer